# WPF Covering area taken by Grid Row (or better, covering 2 rows)

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a grid with 3 rows.  Row #2 is tallest and it hosts WebBrowser control.  I want to cover webbrowser with a Border at certain times.

What is WPF way to do that?

What I have below is my starter xaml.  I use Visibility to collapse my border to show WebBrowser or set my Border to Visible to cover WebBrowser.

However, after doing so I end up having half of 2nd row covered with browser and other half with nothing.

Basically, I want to simulate a toast message that shows and covers entire area of WebBrowser control in GridRow 2.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                  Grid.Row="2">
        <WebBrowser x:Name="wb"
            Loaded="wb_Loaded"/>           
    </ScrollViewer>

    <Border x:Name="myBorder" Background="White" 
            Visibility="Collapsed" 
            Grid.Row="2" RowSpan="2">
        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Center">
            //some text here
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>

     <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="3">
        ...
     </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: `Grid.Row` indexes start at 0. Both the `ScrollViewer` and the `DockPanel` occupy the same row.

Comment: Use a `Grid` in Row:2 and show/hide `Border/BrowserControl`, as `Grid` allows you to stack things on top of each other.

Comment: @Funk That is correct, I know that.  I want to show one or the other at different times (which is unimportant for the question) but want them both to occupy the whole area once they are shown.  Thanks

Comment: @AnjumSKhan Thanks, that works.  If you post it as an answer, I will accept it.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `Grid` in `Row:2` and show/hide `Border/BrowserControl`, as `Grid` allows you to stack things on top of each other.